# Oracle query- How subtract or add days in the given date

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT * From HDB.MDTA E WHERE E.MODIFIED_DAY_KEY BETWEEN TO_CHAR(${pEND_DATE}, 'YYYYMMDD') AND  TO_CHAR(${pEND_DATE}, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

I need help to know how I can subtract or add few days to second date to have a range.

Comment: You can just use `+` or `-` do add days (as a `number`) to a `date`.

Comment: But your query has some potential problems. a) `BETWEEN` with the same upper boundary as the lower one is just an `=`. b) `modified_day_key` seems to be of a string type. It shouldn't. Use proper data types. `date` in this case. c) You probably shouldn't use `BETWEEN` anyway. Most likely you want `>=` the lower boundary and `<` the upper boundary plus one day. Otherwise you'll miss values on the same day but past 00:00:00.000.

Comment: d) It seems like you do string concatenation or interpolation to get values into queries. Don't, that's error prone any might result in an SQL injection vulnerability. Use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, you need to change the upper date of "BETWEEN" clause.

In this case that clause might look like this

```
SELECT * 
  From HDB.MDTA E 
 WHERE E.MODIFIED_DAY_KEY BETWEEN TO_CHAR(${pEND_DATE}, 'YYYYMMDD') AND  TO_CHAR(${pEND_DATE} + 123, 'YYYYMMDD');
```

The "123" is the number of days that will get added to the pEND_DATE parameter

Comment: SELECT * 
  FROM HDB.MDTA E 
 WHERE E.MODIFIED_DAY_KEY BETWEEN                      
      CASE WHEN Count <=30  THEN  TO_CHAR(${pEND_DATE} -40, 'YYYYMMDD')        
     ELSE  TO_CHAR(${pEND_DATE} -30, 'YYYYMMDD')                                                     
     AND  TO_CHAR(${pEND_DATE} , 'YYYYMMDD');